# How to estimate parameters of geometric brownian motion with time-varying mean?

Tags: stochastic-processes, modeling, calibration

Does anyone know how to estimate $A$, $\sigma_1$,$\sigma_2$ from the following system?

$$dx = \mu_t x dt + \sigma_1 x dB_x$$

$$d\mu = A(\bar\mu - \mu) dt + \sigma_2 dB_\mu$$

Variation in $x$ could be either attributed to variation in $\mu$, or variation in $dB_x$, right?

Suppose I know $\bar \mu$, but need to estimate all the rest of the parameters.

Comment: Please have a look at what I did to make sure your math formatting appears properly next time.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to see where you got this model from (or did you come up with it)? Didn't this source provide any clues on how to calibrate? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the assume correlation between $B_\mu$ and $B_x$?

Comment: which kind of estimation of the model do you have in mind? estimation to time-series data? option prices?

Answer (score 3):

I would say

1. Take log of first equation to get rid of dependence on $x_t$
2. Apply Kalman filter equations to estimate parameters

I believe [Conrad and Kaul (1988) J of Business](http://ww.e-m-h.org/ConradKaul1988.pdf) do exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use of your model as pointed out in the comments.
If a discretized version is sufficient then state space models could be a solution.

You can check out the free online [textbook](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/6) by Athana­sopou­los and Hyndman. State space model describe time series in terms of level/trend (and seasonality) on an additive or multiplicative way. There are nice procedure and packages to estimate and forecast such models.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. Sorry for the late reply, I just solved it in matlab using maximum likelihood estimation. Turns out that all we need to do is to specify a state space model, then estimate the coefficient using MLE. The linearity and normality here makes things pretty simple.

Comment: What would actually be awesome is if could post your code here! I'm sure it would definitely help other people in the future!